# Help me to get some tzBTC Token on Testnet

Tags: faucet, testnet

We are integrating the tzBTC in our wallet. For testing we need tzBTC coins

Comment: Do you still need testnet tzBtc tokens, if so add a comment with your pkh on carthagenet and i will send you some.

Comment: This is my pkh: tz1bLc9o6tZhEbmK4az21GyYZfhVf82KR4Nc